# How to use \graphicspath + epstopdf

Tags: graphics, eps, epstopdf

Background:
I am using MiKTeK and TeXnicCenter.  Since I am using Windows, I have to deal with folders whose names have spaces, such as
       `C:/Documents and Settings/...`
and I use `\usepackage[space]{grffile}` to deal with this problem.

Problem:
I saved a bunch of .`eps` figures in a folder and I use the `\graphicspath` to specify that folder in my LaTeX document.  I tried to things to get a PDF with pictures:

1) If I use the package `epstopdf` then it doesn't know that it must save the PDF version of the figure in that folder, and it just complains that it cannot find the figure.  It ends up producing a PDF file without pictures.

2) If I use LaTeX => PS => PDF compilation, then it complains it cannot find the figure, but shows it anyway (!?).  The problem is that it displays the picture in a chaotic manner.  puts all the pictures I try to load in the first page.  (This is a document with several pages, and pictures).

Attempted solutions:

1) If I write a short LaTeX file in my pictures' folder with the `epstopdf` package, then it saves a PDF version of my pictures in that folder.  Later, when I try to compile the document I am trying to produce, it works just fine.  But that is a hassle...

---

This is added by xport. In my previous answer (that I have deleted), JJ O said as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> 1) If I use the package `epstopdf` then it doesn't know that it must save the PDF version of the figure in that folder, and it just complains that it cannot find the figure. It ends up producing a PDF file without pictures.

Have you tried the command `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}` (to be executed *after* the `epstopdf` package is loaded)? This should write the PDF files in the same directory as your main file.

Comment: I tried this after reading your answer.  But it did not work.  If I understood it correctly, I should keep:
(a) \graphicspath pointing to the folder containing the pictures  
(b) \epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}.
  This should save the pictures in the folder where I have my latex document.  Doing exactly this, it didn´t work (notice that, when using the \includegraphics command I just put the file name, expecting that it knows the directory containing the images - perhaps this is what I am getting wrong?)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico for your suggestion.  Without your help I wouldn´t learn about outdir=./.  I am now using it quite a lot in different circunstances and helps wonders!

Answer (score 5):

If you want a graphic (or any other file) available to several LaTeX documents, the normal way is to put it in a local tree rather than referred to by path. Thus for example I keep my shared graphics (logos, *etc.*) in `%USERPROFILE%\texmf\tex\latex\local`. The location of `%USERPROFILE%` varies a bit, but as you seem to be using Windows XP it will be `C:\Document and Settings\<username>`. You can do the same inside `My Documents`, but do need to have the `tex\latex\...` structure.

Create the appropriate structure, then using the MiKTeX Package Manager add the root (in my example, `%USERPROFILE%\texmf`) as a local package folder. MiKTeX should now be able to find your graphics files without needing `\graphicspath`.

The alternative is to do the conversion yourself, then use a *relative* inclusion path. For example, if you have a structure

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\My Documents\Project\LaTeX\main.tex
C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\My Documents\Project\OtherStuff\graphic.eps
```

then you can use the Command Line version of `epstopdf` to do the conversion, giving you a file

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myuser\My Documents\Project\OtherStuff\graphic.pdf
```

This would then be included in `main.tex` using `\graphicspath{{../OtherStuff/}}`. (Automatic conversion cannot happen for a file which needs a `../` or absolute path as this is a security issue.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. if I got it right, your alternative solution is what I stated in the "Attempted Solutions" part of the original question?  If not, I am missing something that could help me a lot.

In your first suggestion, can I put subfolders inside this mother folder texmf\tex\latex\local?

Comment: OK, just manage to pull it off using relative paths.  It is then not a security problem.  More precisely, it on the answer given below.

Answer (score 3):

Run your document with `xelatex` then you do not need the package `epstopdf`. `xelatex` does the conversion on the fly.

Comment: But it will do this conversion at every run, thus slowing the compilation time.

Comment: Thank you, Herbert.  I will try to learn about xelatex now.

Comment: Would you know if it is possible to write a code in my document (a macro?) that tells the program to save a copy of a file in a new folder?

Comment: that can be done with using package `auto-pst-pdf`, it saves all eps images in a container file `<file>-pics.pdf` one image per page

Comment: what about a general file?  I can ask it to make a copy of a eps file into a new folder?

Comment: what about a general file?  I can ask it to make a copy of a eps file into a new folder?  That would solve all the problems in one go.  Latex copy the eps to the folder where my main.tex is, then compiles as usual.  To put the cherry on top of the ice-cream, I would need a code that tells latex to delete the eps figures in the end of the compilation.

Comment: I mean, no need to convert eps to pdf while saving a new copy of the eps document.

Comment: that depends on the number of files you have. For a large bunber a simple shell script or as a one line from the terminal one can convert all files from eps to pdf and then using only the pdf files in the document.

Comment: could it be made from inside my main latex file?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me in the end:

1. Make sure that the folders between your main LaTeX file and the eps figures do not have space in their names
2. when using the `\includegraphics` command, use relative a directory specification.  For example, in my case I use

   ```
   \begin{figure}[h! ht]  

   \includegraphics[width=0.3 \textwidth{../../ProjectName/Output/Images/surv.eps}

   \end{figure}
   ```

   In particular, I went back two folders and then opened the folder 
   `/ProjectName/Output/Images/`.
3. If you do not like the idea of having to write `../../ProjectName/Output/Images/` all the time, write a newcommand

   ```
   \newcommand{\directions}{../../ProjectName/Output/Images/}
   ```

   and then when using `\includegraphics`, use

   ```
   \includegraphics[width=0.3 \textwidth]{\directions surv.eps}
   ```

   (does this defeat the purpose of using `\graphicspath`?)

This approach works with the restriction that the folders name between the main LaTeX file and the figure file do not have space in between. (So, in a nutshell, I believe that something went wrong along the way that `\usepackage[space]{grffile}` was not able to fix, for  I tried several combinations using `\graphicspath` and `\epstopdfsetup`, both using latex => ps => pdf   and `\usepackage{epstopdf}` but none seemed to work.  Besides when you use `epstopdf` in the following manner: save a copy of your document first in the Images folder, compile it, and then compile your main LaTeX file again in the original folder.)

Overall, from this exercise in LaTeX, it seems to me that the latex => ps => pdf compiles much faster than the `\usepackage{epstopdf}` approach.

Comment: So what is the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: Please see the time stamp of my answer, it was july 15 but I deleted because there was no response. :-)

Comment: (you mean the answer right below this one?) I guess I did not understood the part of the batch file.

Comment: Open a file using Notepad, type the given code as if, save as `automatic.bat` (don't forget to choose `Save as type: all files` rather than `Save as type: text document (txt)`).

Comment: I tried so many things I don´t know exactly what was what, but you seem to use the graphicspath command - and I recall having difficultis with it even when using a relative path.

Comment: Please try mine as is. Don't use your setting first. If it does not work then I will proceed to the next investigation. If you mix your configuration and mine, I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Yep, I ran now with 
\graphicspath{{../../restofmystuff}}
and seem to work fine (at least for the latex => ps => pdf).

Comment: Is there an improvement in running this batch file etc?  My TeXnicCenter is working fine, and with the two lines of "code" provided in my answer all is running OK.

Comment: `pdflatex` will not work if your input file imports EPS so `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`  or `xelatex` is used to compile. There is no improvement using batch file. I provided this batch file because I want to minimize the surface of investigation. If TeXnicCenter works, then use it.

Comment: cool, thanks for letting me know!  This whole thing seems to be quite delicate, a little change and bamn, all goes wrong =).  I am using latex => ps => pdf.  It has worked with what I wrote above.  Also, changing to latex => pdf, and using \usepackage{pstopdf}, also works with what is written above, but seems to run much slower.  Thanks a lot again xport!

Comment: see my update in my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following steps. It has been tested and works perfectly.

1. Setup your directory structures as follows.

   - `Images` and `Project` directories are in `xport` directory.

     [image]
   - All EPS images are in  `Images` directory.

     [image]
   - The main input file, named `main.tex` is in `Project` directory.

     [image]
2. Write the main input file, named `main.tex` as follows.

   ```
   % main.tex
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \graphicspath{{../Images/}}

   \begin{document}
   This is a figure \includegraphics{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Create a batch file using Notepad, as follows.

   ```
   rem automatic.bat takes input file name without extension.
   echo off
   latex %1
   dvips %1
   ps2pdf %1.ps
   ```

   You are recommended to save this batch file in `Project` folder for simplicity,  named it as `automatic.bat`. Note: don't forget to choose `Save as type: All Files`.

   [image]

   [image]
4. On the command prompt, change to `Project` directory and type`automatic main` without `.tex` extension, and hit enter as follows.

   [image]
5. Done! You get the `main.pdf` as follows.

   [image]

---

Update in response to JJO's own answer:

1. When you choose `latex=>ps=>pdf` output profile, TeXniCCenter internally invokes commands that I specify in my `automatic.bat`. This workflow is designed for compiling an input file (file with .tex extension) that imports EPS.
2. When you choose `latex=>pdf` output profile, TeXniCCenter internally invokes a command as in

   ```
   rem xport.bat
   echo off
   pdflatex %1
   ```

   This workflow is designed for compiling an input file (file with .tex extension) that imports PDF, PNG, JPEG.
3. `latex=>pdf` output profile can be used to compile input file that imports EPS whenever you load `epstopdf` package. But the compilation becomes slower because each of your existing EPS will be converted to PDF first. Therefore, I suggest you don't use `latex=>pdf` output profile. It is not efficient!!!!