# Why is LaTeX refusing to create a new page to place content?

Tags: macros, errors, pdftex, titles

Ihave stumbled upon strange behavior (at least for me). I am generating a document composed of a set of blank framed boxes, each with a text attached above, and it will always be most likely necessary to span more than page. But as soon as the number of boxes-texts warrants a new page, pdfLaTeX simply refuses to do so, throwing a "Missing $ inserted" error.

I'm attaching my source, trying as much as possible to keep it short. The `companylogo` is placed next to this .tex file (But curious enough, it does not appear in the output).

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize,twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}  % The original content is written in spanish.
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{array}   
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

% Document margins
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

% Headers Config.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{2.5cm} 
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2.22cm}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\includegraphics[height=2.22cm]{companylogo}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}

% Footers Config.
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
% Use dot as decimal point
\decimalpoint
% Enable page-broken equations
\allowdisplaybreaks[2]
% Command macros
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\emptybox}[2]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{#1}\hfill\vspace{#2}\end{minipage}}}
\newcommand{\elembox}[1]{\begin{center}#1 \\ \emptybox{3cm}{3cm} \end{center}}

\title{SomeTitle}

% Remove author and date info from title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{
 \vspace{-2cm}
 \begin{center}%
  {\LARGE \@title}%
 \end{center}%
 \par} \makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\elembox{1206 (1)}
\elembox{2512 (2)}
\elembox{0805 (1)}
\elembox{carbon-resistor-0.5W (1)}
\elembox{oar-5 (1)}
\elembox{1206 (2)}
\elembox{0603 (2)}
\elembox{2416 (1)}
\elembox{oar-5 (1)}
\elembox{carbon-resistor-0.5W (1)}
\elembox{qfn40 (1)}
\elembox{dip44 (2)}
% Up to this many \elemboxes this compiles. but if you uncomment the one below, BOOM.

% \elembox{dip8 (2)}
% More \elemboxes to follow, but starting from the one above, pdfLaTeX throws the error.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the point at which you get a page break. If I uncomment the last one I get the error that companylogo is not found. If I replace the includegraphics with "AAAA" it works without error, so I guess it is failing while reading the eps file to find the bounding box.

Comment: I don't get any error (at least not after using the `demo` option for `graphicx` to ignore the missing `companylogo`). I enabled the last `\elembox`, which should have been enabled from the start. Examples should always produce the error.

Comment: If I use one of my images instead of your logo, your example works OK in my system. What happens if you add demo to `graphicx`; i.e., if you load the package like this: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`?

Comment: I seem to remember that the spanish babel setup has some "interesting" catcode assignments which may trip up characters that appear in that file if they appear before the bounding box.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I didn't know about the `demo` option in `graphicx`. The code compiled correctly with this option set. 

In other to make it work without it (and so making the `companylogo` appear), I had to use the file's absolute path (I was using the path relative to `~/`, which seems not to work. I have always worked with relative paths containing `../` without an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments your code works well.

Something goes wrong with your picture. However LaTeX can handle relative paths.

A relative path is setup with `../`. You can also use `\graphicspath`:

[How to use \graphicspath + epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23141/how-to-use-graphicspath-epstopdf)

Note that spaces in paths need special handling.

There might also be a problem in using `~/` for denoting a path, as `~` has special meaning. You might try `\string~/` instead.