# Using eps figures with graphicspath

Tags: graphics, eps

I am having an issue with using .eps figures and the \graphicspath{} command. I was trying to keep things organized by placing all my figures in a folder /Figures, so the folder structure looks like:

```
/project
    /figures
        figure.eps
    /report
        report.tex
```

My original solution looked like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,reprint,showkeys,nofootinbib,twoside]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../figures/}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{figure.eps}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This works fine if the figure is a .png, but with the eps I get the "couldn't find figure-converted-to-pdf" error.

I then tried the solution in [How to use \graphicspath + epstopdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23141/how-to-use-graphicspath-epstopdf) , like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,reprint,showkeys,nofootinbib,twoside]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
\graphicspath{{../figures/}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{figure.eps}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but with this solution all that happens is the previous error no longer appears, and the result is empty space where the figure should be (not even the little box with the path that appears if the figure isn't found).

My current workaround is to just dump all my figures in the same directory as my .tex file, but this becomes rather messy with lots of .eps figures. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get (as I expected) an error `!!! Error: Output filename '../figures/inparent-eps-converted-to.pdf' not allowed in restricted mode.`. With this setup epstopdf would have to write to a parent folder and the security settings shouldn't allow this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh parents ah yes.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wonder why the error was suppressed on my setup? Regardless, I think I’ll just convert my figures to pdf ahead of time, and avoid using epstopdf.

Comment: But your second example with the `outdir` worked fine for me. Which tex system are you using?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I’m using texlive.

Comment: which version? And on which OS?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Results of tex —version : TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)